# making a web service ? How to make its WSDL?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services

I am making a web service and I am new to web services. Please guide me how to make WSDL for my .Net web service ( it is no WCF service).

Please also guide me where I will place WSDL file, on client or server side ? where I will place WSDL file.

Thanks

Comment: How have you created the web service? It is an `asmx` file? Something else? If so, what?

Comment: what you have done so far ???

Comment: Oded it is asmx file, please guide.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

MSDN : [Web Services Description Language Tool (Wsdl.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

use Wsdl.exe utility in visual studio 2008 for web services

you must run that tool from command prompt ,

Start - > all programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 - > Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt

Comment: Thanks.

Please guide will this file be stored on server ? Will it be complied ?

How I will give its address to client use ?

Answer (score 1):

To generate wsdl file, you must use wsdl.exe from visual studio command prompt. But if you expect to use wsdl in your solution projects, in visual studio, you can click on project, choose add web service/service reference -> choose your service from solution or url and then VS automatically generate all file for you

Comment: Thanks Vitaly Zemlyansky,

After generating file where I will place this file ? Will it be compiled as well ?

Comment: After you generate code file, it will be your proxy class file - place it where you need access to web service in your client code. Yes it will be compiled well, because when you do this by visual studio, I mean use add web reference, VS use this util for create proxy class.

Answer (score 1):

Use Wsdl.exe as suggested by Pranay Rana and put it on the **server**.

To access web service on a client .Net side create a service reference in visual studio to get the client proxy.

Comment: Thanks @Be.St.

Where WSDL file will be hosted ? On server ? plz guide

Comment: Yes wsdl must be on the server

Comment: How I will give its address to client use ?

Comment: The .wsdl file is not compiled, simply copy it to the destination.
For client you must access the .asmx file.

Comment: Be.St. please guide what do you mean by destination ? Do you mean shared hosting ? If client will only access asmx file what will use of WSDL ? Is it not provided to client ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just using ASMX based webservices, correct?

If you want to generate a WSDL on an ASP.NET/ASMX site, you can run the web application and hit the ASMX URL with the querystring "?WSDL".  So if your service name is

`http://myserver/myservice.asmx`

then you can hit

`http://myserver/myservice.asmx?wsdl`

Save the page locally and you can send it to whomever needs it.  Exposing the WSDL is enabled by default, the person or company who needs to consume the WSDL can generate it by hitting the URL as well.